# iPad splitview application with core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, core-data, uisplitviewcontroller

I am new in app development and I have really big issues with my split view core data iPad application. Even though I made sure that  I have built all core data structure very well, I have problems when I pass objects between view and saving them via core data. Basically my problem is in this way:
I have peopleviewcontroller where I list all people in list. And I have addpersonviewcontroller where I create new person and save it to coredata. However, even though saving new object in new class seems successful in save-error structure, no data is written to core data. I debuted the code and figured out that managedjectcontext of created person is always null. Hence, it is not written to core data.
I have spent really lots and lots of time for solution, including days of reading stackverflow, but no solution.
Any help about this issue is deeply appreciated. Thabk you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Person is a subclass of NSManagedObject. In your AddPersonViewController, you never created the object. You have to use insert that entity into core data before you save it.

I recommend having some store/repository that handles all of this.

For instance, I have this in my code:

```
- (NSManagedObject *)createManagedObject:(NSString *)entityName
{
    NSManagedObject *objectCreated = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    [self saveContext];
    return objectCreated;
}
```

I then call it with the entity type and it returns a NSManagedObject. You can then cast it to your Person class with

Person *addPerson = (Person *)managedObject;

Now you can make your changes and save it.

A NSManagedObject must be created by the store before it can be saved. You cannot just new it up and expect it to work.

Comment: Hello Justin, Thank you very much for your answer.if you noticed, I have created addPerson object in the PeopleViewController,in prepareForSegue method. You mean that I should recreate it?

Comment: The add person is saving, There is an error displaying them in your table view.

Comment: Thank you again. I looked at data via sqllite. However, There seems no data.

Comment: Moreover, If you noticed, the app gets following error: 2014-09-05 03:04:20.550 MasterDetailStoryboard[4232:60b] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  -[UITableViewCell setPerson:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e67c80 with userInfo (null)

Comment: Hello Justin. You were right ! Thank you very very much I have solved the problem.